# Is there a command to dump local variables in a bash script?

Tags: bash

I have many scripts where I make use variables within the scripts.  While the script is running, can I issue a command within the script to dump all of the variables and their values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are after a way of helping you debug your script, you could put

```
set -x
```

At the beginning of your script that will display command traces including how your variables are used.

Answer (score 4):

The command `env` on its own should display all the variables.

The builtin command `set` on its own will also dump the variables.

Note that inherited variables will also be dumped.

Comment: set will also dump any defined functions in your .bashrc or .bash_profile file(s).